# mongodb query with comparison of property of itself

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have such documents

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("524a498ee4b018b89437f88a"),
   "counter": {
     "0": {
       "date": "2013.9",
       "counter": NumberInt(1425) 
    },
     "1": {
       "date": "2013.10",
       "counter": NumberInt(1425) 
    } 
  },
   "profile": ObjectId("510576242b5e30877c654aff") 
}
```

and i wanted to search for those, where the counter.0.counter not equals counter.1.counter

tryed

```
db.counter.find({"profile":ObjectId("510576242b5e30877c654aff"),"counter.0.counter":{$ne:"counter.1.counter"}  });
```

but it says its not a valid json query :/
an help ?

Comment: So I really hope your data does not look like this really and it is actually a PHP dump of sorts. Because that is not a good way to represent this structure and I hope that "counter" (top level) is actually a **real** array.

Comment: well, this is how its stored in the database, and counter is not a real array its a real hash map

Comment: A hash map is not the ideal form for this but it does not actually change the appoach. You are probably better off using arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

You cannot actually compare like this unless resorting to JavaScript or using the aggregation framework. The form with aggregate is the better option:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "counter": 1,
        "matched": { "$eq": [
            "$counter.0.counter",
            "$counter.1.counter"
        ]}
    }},
    { "$match": { "matched": true } }
])
```

Or with the bad use of JavaScript:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$where": function() {
        return this.counter.0.counter == this.counter.1.counter;
    }
})
```

So those are the ways this can be done.

The big problems with the JavaScript **`$where`** operator are:

- Invokes the JavaScript interpreter to evaluate every result document and is not native code.
- Removes any opportunity to use an index to find the results as needed. By other methods you can actually use an index with a a separate "match" condition. But this operator removes that chance.

Comment: @Dikesh You shouldn't be trying the second approach if you actually read the response. Also not your question so why are you even here?